# Changing the color of font from php variable

Tags: php, html, css

I've got a reed switch on a GPIO pin on a Raspberry Pi, monitoring if a door is open or closed.

This displays OK in a browser:

```
<?php
echo "Today is " . date("l, jS F Y") . "<br>";
?>
</br>

<?php
 // Set up valid status list
$state[1] = "open";
$state[0] = "closed";
?>

<p style="font-family: calibri; font-size:14pt; font-style:italic">
The door is currently
<?php $pinStatus = trim(shell_exec("gpio -g read 18"));
//returns 0 = low; 1 = high
echo $state[$pinStatus];?>
</p>
```

I'd like to have the words 'open' and 'closed' in different colours, but cannot see how to do this. Open/closed can be bold easily enough, but making them coloured seems quite tricky.

Comment: ^^^^ and some basic chapter 1 use of the IF statement

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp

Answer (score 6):

```
$state[1] = '<span style="color:green">open</span>';
$state[0] = '<span style="color:red">closed</span>';
```

Comment: Edited code from @alariva tested and works perfectly too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pure PHP and HTML+CSS, and there are many ways to achieve this.

Follows a quick and dirty solution that does the trick. You may be willing to learn [PHP and control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

```
<p style="font-family: calibri; font-size:14pt; font-style:italic">
The door is currently
<?php $pinStatus = trim(shell_exec("gpio -g read 18"));
//returns 0 = low; 1 = high

$label = $state[$pinStatus];

if($label == $state[1])
{
   echo "<span style=\"color:green\">$label</span>";
}
else
{
   echo "<span style=\"color:red\">$label</span>";
}

?>
</p>
```

Comment: The solution from alariva gave a blank page, whereas that from @p3tch worked perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. There was a syntax error. Try the edited code.